# HTML tags that are not marked as inline code disappear

Tags: support, markdown

I am wondering if it is intentionally that `_std::vector<char>_` is being displayed as *std::vector* (the bracket embracing char is missing) when I not use the ``.  I just wanted to use it in a text.

Apparently it gets interpreted as HTML, but since it is not in the subset it gets removed. IMHO thats not the best implementation. If it is *not in subset* or if it is *not closed* it would be better to *just be displayed as text* to help the author see the problem or to just show something that was not intentioned as a html-tag.

What do you think?

Comment: Inline HTML interpretation is intentional. If you want to present code, do as you did in your post here as specifying `std::vector<char>` as inline code using the backticks.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ What you are saying is true, but this request isn't asking to disable inline HTML interpretation, but rather to fall through and display the unformated source if no valid HTML tag is matched.

Answer (score 7):

This is not a bug. The Stack Overflow post editor supports a *limited set* of HTML tags, including:

- `<strong>`
- `<em>`
- `<strike>`
- `<code>`
- `<blockquote>`
- `<br>`
- `<a>`
- and more… (this is not a comprehensive list, just an example; see [here for the full list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1777/what-html-tags-are-allowed-on-stack-exchange-sites))

Nearly all of these can also be achieved using the appropriate [Markdown syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) (with `<strike>` being the only exception), but we still support the HTML tags.

That means things like std::vector<char> get displayed as std::vector because it interprets <char> as being the HTML tag `<char>`. Which isn't an HTML tag, and even if it were, not one that the sanitizer supports.

This is, of course, why we have inline code formatting, so that you can type things like `std::vector<char>`. Any time you want to type *code*, you should use inline code formatting. It not only ensures that characters aren't misinterpreted and swallowed by the post formatting engine, but it also serves a semantic and visual function of designating it as code.

***However, please do not abuse the inline formatting feature to "highlight" things that are not code!***

If you absolutely insist on typing things like `std::vector<char>` *without* using inline code formatting, then you can escape the angle brackets using `&lt;` and `&gt;`. (This is what I did above to get std::vector<char> to display.) All of the escape sequences that I've occasioned to tried so far have worked, including —, →, ←, …, ±, ∞, ©, etc.

Comment: What would you think of requiring that certain formatting errors, including unrecognized angle-bracket tags, be fixed before a submission would be accepted?  If someone writes "vector&lt;char&gt;" without the backticks, they almost certainly do not intend it to be shown as simply "vector". I think asking the user to fix the post would almost certainly be better than posting something the user does not intend, especially if--in cases where intent could be 90% inferred--the system could offer buttons to either apply a particular fix or let the user resume editing.

Comment: I don't know, most UX experts would disagree that showing an error and rejecting the submission is preferable to just doing what is most reasonable. I guess you could bomb on all unrecognized strings in angle brackets, that just doesn't seem necessary. You're supposed to look at the preview before you hit submit to make sure that it's what you want. I think it would be confusing to automatically interpret *certain* angle brackets as HTML code, but *not* others.

Comment: I would consider the behavior analogous rejecting a comment which exceeds the length limit, versus simply truncating it.  In most cases there will be two and sometimes three things the person might have intended when code contains what looks like an invalid tag; if the user selects one of those choices, then the post will appear as intended.  If the software tries to guess, it's apt to be wrong much of the time.